# Node.js: Upload large file to MongoDB AND data from text inputs on the same page to different collections

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Hello there and Happy New Year to all:)

In the .ejs file there are two forms: one to get text inputs, another for file upload:

```
<div class="sectionContainer">
  
            <div class="tour-upload">
              <form method="post" action="/office/new-tour">
                <label for="tourHeading">Tour Heading <em>&#x2a;</em></label
                ><input
                  id="tourHeading"
                  name="tourHeading"
                  required=""
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="eg May 31-June 11 (Riga, Amsterdam, Riga)"
                />

                <label for="tourDescription"
                  >Tour Info <em>&#x2a;</em></label
                >
                <textarea
                  id="tourDescription"
                  name="tourDescription"
                  required=""
                  placeholder="Add tour details"
                  rows="4"
                ></textarea>


                <button id="add-tour">Add Tour</button>
              </form>


<form action="office/add-score" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="custom-file mb-3">
          <input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="custom-file-input">
          <label for="file" class="custom-file-label">Choose File</label>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
      </form>

            </div>
```

In order to get get the info from the form where `action="/office/new-tour"`, I can use this code in app.js:

Setup:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const http = require("http");
const url = require("url");

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
```

And the actual code with logic:

```
app.get("/office", function (req, res) {
  

  res.render("office");

});


//Mongo DB connection for form data saving

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/kbTourAppDB", {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});


const ToursSchema = {
  tour: { tourHeading: String, tourDescription: String },
  program: { tourProgram: String, tourProgramDescription: String },
};

const Tour = mongoose.model("Tour", ToursSchema);

app.post("/office/new-tour", (req, res) => {

  const addedTour = new Tour({
    tour: {
      tourHeading: req.body.tourHeading,
      tourDescription: req.body.tourDescription,
    },
    program: {
      tourProgram: req.body.tourProgram,
      tourProgramDescription: req.body.tourProgramDescription,
    },
    //add author when the login page is ready
  });

  addedTour.save(function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("err: ", err);
    } else {
      console.log("sucess added new Tour to db");
    }
  });

  res.redirect("/office");
});


app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log("listening on port 3000");
});
```

The code above works successfully for getting those text inputs to database, however I can't use it to upload the files to the database (mostly jpeg and pdf). For that I found a solution with Multer and GridFS.

Set up:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");


const path = require("path");
const crypto = require("crypto");
const multer = require("multer");
const GridFsStorage = require("multer-gridfs-storage");
const Grid = require("gridfs-stream");
const methodOverride = require("method-override");


const http = require("http");
const url = require("url");

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(methodOverride("_method"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
```

And code here:

```
app.get("/office", function (req, res) {
  

  res.render("office");

});

const conn = mongoose.createConnection("mongodb://localhost:27017/kbTourAppDB");

let gfs;

conn.once("open", () => {
  gfs = Grid(conn.db, mongoose.mongo);
  gfs.collection("uploads");
});

//create storage object
const storage = new GridFsStorage({
  url: "mongodb://localhost:27017/kbTourAppDB",
  file: (req, file) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      crypto.randomBytes(16, (err, buf) => {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }
        const filename = buf.toString("hex") + path.extname(file.originalname);
        const originalFileName = file.originalname;
        const fileInfo = {
          filename: filename,
          bucketName: "uploads",
        };
        resolve(fileInfo);
      });
    });
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage });






app.post("/office/add-score", upload.single("file"), (req, res) => {
  res.redirect("/office");
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log("listening on port 3000");
});
```

This code works for uploading files to database..

How can I write a code that will allow me to do both on the same page: upload the text input data to the MongoDB collection 'tour-data' for example, and the files from the other form to the collection 'uploads'..

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually when using multer, the text-fields from your form should still be populated under `req.body.<field-name>`, so you should be able to just use your initial code for inserting the tour-data:

```
app.post("/office/add-score", upload.single("file"), (req, res) => {
  const addedTour = new Tour({
    tour: {
      tourHeading: req.body.tourHeading,
      tourDescription: req.body.tourDescription,
    },
    program: {
      tourProgram: req.body.tourProgram,
      tourProgramDescription: req.body.tourProgramDescription,
    }
  });
  addedTour.save(...)
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Using the suggestion you provided, I could get the info from `req.body` (could console.log() it, etc) but couldn't upload it to database , I think, because it wasn't connected to the right connection and without file being attached it didn't go to the uploads bucket. When I added, what I understand, is a second connection `mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/kbTourAppDB", {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});`
everything started working, and now I can upload from two different forms to two different collections. Thank you!

Comment: Great you figured it out, happy I could help :)